# Bufferedreader next line after read() method

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Let's say I need to input character and afterwards a word. Here is my piece of code, but I don't think it'll help in this particular case.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
char letter = (char)reader.read();
String input = reader.readLine();
```

So if I enter `d` and press Enter, I will terminate the program. The only possible solution is to enter character, press Space and enter the word.

However, I'm eager to know how to enter the word from the next line. If I switch **String** with **char** it will work (assumebly because `readLine()` moves to the new line).

Usually I would not write here to find out answers for some small questions, but this time my Google skills failed me. Will appreciate any guidance:)

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you press `d`, reader.read() will return `d` and reader.readLine() will start reading input. If you then press `Enter`, readLine() returns the empty String `""`. If you, for example, press `abc[Enter]`, then `letter` will contain `a` and `input` will contain `bc`. Which different behaviour did you expect? Maybe you assumed that read() will also wait for a `newline` character?

Comment: Well yes. Unfortunately can't paste picture in the answer. Please see the link I've added to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate `buffered reader` two times then you can get string in next line after entering character

```
    BufferedReader reader; 

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    char letter = (char)reader.read();

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: Thanks. Never even knew you can do this.
No, not like this. Better to rephrase.
Will it be to instances of a class BufferedReader?

Comment: @Andrew Yes they are two difference instances of BufferedReader.